# Assuming something has remained Kosher

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, chazaka

When someone buys a product with Kosher certification, do they have to check to make sure that it is still certified Kosher or can they rely on the fact that the last time (or first time) they bought it it had certification?  For how long can someone rely on the previous time they checked?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13794/759

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the answers there would not apply here (which I think demonstrates it isn't a dupe, but correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @DoubleAA meaning, shelf-items do not have dates on their hechsherim, for starters.

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13776/759

Comment: @DoubleAA That one is even more similar, but it is talking about a case where what you are verifying is if this is the same food as it was years ago.  Here, you know it is the same, and want to know if it has dropped certification. (I.e. there you want to know if this is still Planters.  Here you want to know if Planters has remained Kosher.)

Comment: I do not understand the question. It depends how worried the person is about eating something which has lost certification and may possibly not be kosher. But something may be perhaps deduced from the fact that the London Beth Din publishes an [update](http://www.kosher.org.uk/updates.htm) every three months.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok the halacha depends on how worried you personally are?

Comment: It's worth noting that not everything certified kosher has the certification noted on the label, so checking is not always a simple matter of reading the label.

Answer (score 1):

My family used to use a certain brand of margarine that was Pareve for years. We didn't check the Hechsher (Kosher certification) on the product very often, but one day it changed from being Pareve to being dairy. Luckily, we noticed that it had become dairy and we stopped buying that margarine. Had we not checked, it would very likely have led to mixing of meat and milk.

I recommend always looking for a Hechsher.

Comment: I've got one worse, something I used to eat went from milchig to basar b'chalav.

Comment: Oy, that's not cool. Did they added bovine gelatin or something?

Comment: Chicken fat. The hechsher vanished (I then discovered).